# How to handle model.compile calling loss and metric functions with empty data

Tags: python, tensorflow, loss-function

Using tensorflow nightly (2.0), I have custom losses and metrics in my call to model.compile. When running with:

```
tf.config.experimental_run_functions_eagerly(True)
```

everything works fine. If I don't turn on experimental eager execution, for some reason calling:

```
self._model.compile(optimizer="Adam",
                            loss=[
                                balanced_cross_entropy,
                                intersection_over_union,
                                angle_loss
                            ],
                            metrics=[
                                [image_logging_metric('RBOX Score Map')],
                                [image_logging_metric('RBOX Shapes')],
                                [image_logging_metric('RBOX Angles')],
                            ])
```

calls all of my loss and metric function with empty tensors that have dimensions which don't match the shape of my expected inputs. I can't find any documentation about writing loss and metrics differently for graph mode, and don't understand why they are called as part of compilation.

One other thing to note is I have dynamic input shape (None, None, None, 3), and I'm guessing that's why the dimensions passed to my functions are unexpectedly small, but the unspecified shape is intentional and working in eager execution, as everything is scaled with convolutions.

So I'm wondering, why are losses and metrics being called on compile, and is there an intended way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out I just needed to pass target_tensors with desired shapes to compile even though I'm using fit_generator and a Sequence.